# error in excel vba - "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: excel, loops, procedure, vba

i have set of files need to be work out , when i run a macro it should open work book and apply formula and save as text file in a specified folder then go to the next workbook in that folder.

i run the macro its showing error "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" after first file is processed

**error in -     strF = Dir()**

macro is not looking for the second file in the folder

i am new to vba and not aware where is the issue.

Request you to help..

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim n As Integer
Dim filename As String
Dim strF As String, strP As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xWB As Workbook
'Edit this declaration to your folder name
strP = "D:\TEST\INPUT" 'change for the path of your folder
    Do While strF <> vbNullString
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strP & "\" & strF)
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("My file.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("Y:Y").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("Y1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "HEADER"
    Range("Y2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "HEADER"
    Range("Y3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "formula"
        With Range("Y:Y").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "my formula"
          End With
          Range("y3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
      n = 1
    Do
        filename = "D:\GOBI\" & "TEST FILE" & Format(IIf(n = 1, "000001", n), "000000") & ".txt"
        n = n + 1
    Loop Until Dir(filename) = ""
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:= _
        xlText, CreateBackup:=False
         ActiveWorkbook.Close False
For Each xWB In Application.Workbooks
    If Not (xWB Is Application.ActiveWorkbook) Then
        xWB.Close False
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    strF = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That code would **never** reach that line but, if it did, you'd have a problem because you can't nest `Dir` statements like that. It would be better if you just pasted in the *actual full code*.

Comment: Dear  @Rory,thanks for your reply ,But same kind of vba successfully working....

Comment: Same *kind*, maybe, but not *that* code. This line: `Do While strF <> vbNullString` will **NEVER** be true since you haven't assigned a value to `strF`, so the code will simply exit.